# Null and Undefined in QML and C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qml, qt5

When extending QML with custom types written in C++, I started to wonder about differences between JS and C++.

This time I was wondering, if `null`-checks on the C++-side are sufficiant, or if there is something like a "`QUndefined`" that I might need to consider as well. As far as I can see, this is not described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html).

Or to put it differently:

- What happens on the C++ side when I set a property to `undefined` on the QML side
- What happens on the C++ side when I set a property to `null` on the QML side
- What happens on the QML side when I set a property to `null` on the C++ side

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're certainly on the right track with your answer, but here's some more information.

What happens when you write to a property depends on what that property *is*, for instance, is it a QObject property? etc. Depending on the type of the property, you may also get an error on assignment (if for instance you are writing `null` to a numeric type property like double).

Let's assume, for the sake of the answer that you are setting a property on a `QObject`. You may set it to `undefined` if the property has a `RESET` function defined for the Q_PROPERTY. [Quoting the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html):

> A RESET function is optional. It is for setting the property back to its context specific default value. e.g., QWidget::cursor has the typical READ and WRITE functions, QWidget::cursor() and QWidget::setCursor(), and it also has a RESET function, QWidget::unsetCursor(), since no call to QWidget::setCursor() can mean reset to the context specific cursor. The RESET function must return void and take no parameters.

To be more specific, if you have a Q_PROPERTY that has a `RESET` function, when you write `undefined` to that property, [the `RESET` function will be called](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4qobjectwrapper.cpp#L424-L427).

For setting properties to `null`, the answer is located right above that last reference, basically, if the property contains a `QObject*`-derived type, [it will store a `nullptr`](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4qobjectwrapper.cpp#L423).

The last case you ask about is assigning `null` to a property on the C++ side. For intents and purposes, I'm assuming you are asking about a case like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QObjectDerived* myThing READ myThing NOTIFY myThingChanged);

...

QObjectDerived *myThing() { return m_myThing; }

...

void somethingElse() {
    m_myThing = 0; // or NULL, nullptr, whatever floats your boat
    emit myThingChanged();
}
```

In this case, the QML-side of this property (`myInstanceId.myThing`) would end up as `null`, from memory.